# Delete Shared Preferences in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

This is how i add shared preferences

```
    ct = sp.getInt("count", 0);
    if (ct > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= ct; i++) {
            list.add(sp.getString("Value[" + i + "]", ""));
        }
    }
        adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        Listtt.setAdapter(adp);
        btnad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sped.putString("Value[" + ct + "]", editText.getText().toString());
                sped.commit();
                list.add(sp.getString("Value[" + ct + "]", ""));
                ct += 1;
                sped.putInt("count", ct);
                adp.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

And by this i can successfully delete Sharedprefrences Value and remove it from list

```
 sp.edit().remove("key_to_remove").apply();
             adp.remove("name_to_rmv");
             adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Now my problem is that it leaves the blank space when i call it back just like closing activity and opening it again the value i have deleted has the blank space . Just like this image below i have deleted " two " but when i close and open my application it gives me blank space

how i fill adapter

```
 ct = sp.getInt("count", 0);
        if (ct > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= ct; i++) {
                list.add(sp.getString("Value[" + i + "]", ""));
            }
        }
            adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            Listtt.setAdapter(adp);
```

.[image: Example output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've met the same problem. I figured out a way to do this. This may not be the best way but it do what needs to be done. You will have to 
**decrease each and every value after the deleted value in SP by 1**

if you have values in sp like

```
"value[0]","one"
"value[1]","two"
"value[2]","three"
"value[3]","four"
```

after deleted "value[1]", it would be

```
"value[0]","one"
"value[2]","three"
"value[3]","four"
(that's why it returns null string when you try to fetch "value[1]" because there are no such a value)
```

> so make them a continues by inserting "value[1]". That means modify your existing value ("value[**2**]","three") as ("value[**1**]","three"). and apply this to other values also. you can simply do this by with a for loop. Then your final values would be like this.

```
"value[0]","one"
"value[1]","three"
"value[2]","four"
```

As you can see there won't be any  blank spaces when you reading back. You will have to decrease counter by 1 because now there are only 3 values.

```
    void deleteItem(int element_num,int counter,SharedPreferences sp,ArrayAdapter<String> adp){


        //element_num is the element number that you want to delete
        String name_to_rmv=sp.getString("Value[" + element_num + "]", ""); //backup the value that needs to be deleted

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();

        for(int i=element_num;i<counter;i++)
            editor.putString("Value[" + i + "]", sp.getString("Value[" + (i+1) + "]", "")); //read i+1 value and store it to i

        counter--;              //decrease counter
        editor.putInt("count", counter);
        editor.commit();

        adp.remove(name_to_rmv);    
        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Can you give me a code like example by simply editing my code because i get the point which you are saying but how can you implement that ? by making shared prefrences again ?